# Print of web page not fit on A4 page correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am using JavaScript `window.print()` function to print a web page with a header and footer And that web page height is dynamic. It's height is depend on the HTML table on that page. So when table height is large, and when I print that page using `window.print()`, footer image of the web page will set to the middle of printed page. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you looked at setting any print media styles? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: @Nathan: I tried them.

Answer (score 1):

that's the place where you could use @media query. setup a different layout for printer friendly

```
yes, you can use @page {
    counter-increment: page;

    @top-center {
        content: "This is the header that will repeat on every page"
    }
    @bottom-right {
        counter-increment: page;
        content: "Page " counter(page);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I used a different layout if the page size is too big and fit the header and footer for each page??

Comment: look at my demo here:http://jsfiddle.net/7CTbW/1/ You can see the web layout and print layout is totally different. And the header and footer are not overlapped by the content.

Comment: If you just don't want the footer to be in the middle of the page, try add display:block to your footer/table.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the header and footer for every page and change the body of the page only. ?

Comment: yes, see my edit. also you can use thead and tfoot if you are using table

Comment: I can do that, but would be better for you to practice it for yourself. Also if you put your code on jsfiddle people here can better help you.

Comment: I have a very long code for print layout. It has a separate css file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the @media print directive to apply specific CSS styles when a user prints.

@media print {
   …
}

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use this jquery plugin:

```
https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin
```

demo:

```
http://etimbo.github.io/jquery-print-preview-plugin/example/index.html
```

Comment: I need to fix the page layout, not view the print view.

Comment: yes, so just follow this tutorial: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/